# No CameraManager import available on GDK app

Tags: google-glass, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to [execute sample from Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/camera#capturing_images_or_video), but in my code the CameraManager import is not available.

I have tried registering my intent for my activity:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Also requested permissions:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But no way the import `com.google.android.glass.media.CameraManager` becomes available.

By the way, I'm using SDK version 19. Some data from `build.gradle`:

```
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I have the same issue but my compiled version is already correct, did you come across any other solutions to this issue when searching?

Comment: Its OK, the latest release notes state the CameraManager stuff has been moved to Intents.

Comment: I didn't knew about it. Thanks, we just upgraded to latest SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set:

`compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19"`

I am not sure, but you may have to put `gdk.jar` in your `libs/` dir too.

Comment: @KurtMueller You do not have to run this command, just change your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I realized that this is for the IntelliJ IDE and not Eclipse. Sorry for the confusion folks!

Comment: It's not specific to an IDE. I was suggesting a direct change to the Gradle build, but, the SDK name is something you need to specify no matter what build system you use, and the string above is what you need.